# LibreOffice Impress - Discarding image cropped-out data

Tags: libreoffice

I created some presentation with a lot of small images.

The problem is - that those images were originally whole screenshots (1920x1080 px), which I used Impress' image cropping tool to take only small relevant parts of the screenshot.

If you ask why is it a problem -> the answer is that instead of containing ~30 very little image crops, my presentation contains ~30 1920x1080 sized images, and just shows them according to the current crop settings.

It causes the saving process to take ~10 seconds, the output file is very large and everything works slowly because of the complex rendering process.

Is there any way to discard the cropped parts of the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cropping tool is not good for making such large changes.  From  https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Cropping_resizing_rotating (and this is true in Impress as well):

> If you crop an image in Writer, the picture itself is not changed. If
>   you export the document to HTML, the original image is exported, not
>   the cropped image.

Instead, use separate image software to do the cropping before putting the images into Impress.  I typically use [IrfanView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipiufOlrHJAhUJWCYKHUZ3CMEQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.irfanview.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNHUS2rDnW5eC14YE7BxCpDK186zhA&bvm=bv.108194040,d.eWE).

For a discussion see https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3665.